# Recover Fourier Transform of flipped signal from the FFT of orignal signal

Tags: fourier-transform

I trying to recover the Fourier Transform of a flipped signal directly from the Fourier transform of the original signal.

More precisly, let `s` be a random signal:

```
s = np.random.randn(n)
```

Let `s1_fft` and `s2_fft` the Fourier Transform of the signal `s`.

```
s1_fft = np.fft.fft(s)
s2_fft = np.fft.fft(s[::-1])
```

I am trying the find the operation the get `s2_fft` from `s1_fft` withtout having the go back to the time domain.

I'am actually trying to do that with the 2d Fourier Transorm.

Thank you,

Comment: Please see @RickLyons nice write up on time reversal with the DFT here: https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1315.php

Comment: Thank you very much ! that's perfect !

Comment: Maybe if @RickLyons sees this he can provide a very high level summary as an answer below with a link to his very nice write up to close this out.

Comment: I believe my blog at: 'dsprelated.com/showarticle/1315.php' tells the full story of the spectral effects of the two ways of "flipping" a time sequence. Perhaps the  time-reversal method I called "Flip Time-Reversal" should have been called "Biblical Time-Reversal."

"Many that are first shall be last; and the last first." [Mark 10:31]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can start with a the simple DFT relationship of the time reversal, i.e.

If $ \mathcal{F} (x[n])  =  X[k] $, then $ \mathcal{F} (x[-n])  =  X'[k] $, where $'$ denotes complex conjugation.

Now flipping the vector as in your code is NOT just a simple time flip. For a time flip the sample at $n=0$ should stay put. So vector flipping as in your code performs a time flip AND a circular shift by one sample. That shift corresponds to multiplication with $e^{j2\pi k/N}$, where $N$ is the FFT length.

So in order to restore the FFT from the vector flip, you need to undo the shift and then take the conjugate. Here is how this would look in Matlab

```
%% FFT of a vector flip

% random vector
nx = 1024;
x = randn(nx,1);
fx = fft(x);
% flip and FFT
y = x(end:-1:1);
fy = fft(y);

% multiply with inverse shift operator and multiply
w = exp(-1i*2*pi*(0:nx-1)'./nx); % inverse cicular shift
fz = conj(fy.*w);

% calculate error

fprintf('Error = %6.2fdB\n', 10*log10(mean(abs((fz-fx)).^2)./mean(abs(fx.^2))));
```